# python double iterator in list comprehension

Tags: python

so if I have 1's in all the indexes position of S and rest would be 0's. Length of the new string will be N. How do I do that in Python list comprehension

```
S= [2,5,8]
N= 10
Desired output: [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]
```

My Code:

```
newlist = [1 if x.__index__() == S[i]  else 0 for i in range(len(S)) for x in range(N)]

My Output: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward solution is not using a list comprehension:

```py
result = [0] * N
for i in S:
    result[i - 1] = 1
```

Note that `i - 1` is needed to convert the 1-based indices in your list `S` to 0-based indices. If you have 0-based indices in your list (which would be simpler for most purposes), then you can just write `result[i] = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = [1 if i+1 in S else 0 for i in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your S list is using 1-based indexing

```
[int(i in S) for i in range(1, N+1)]
```